# Downloading entire website - freeware software

Tags: software-recommendation, software

Is there any **freeware** software (including command line utilities) to downloaded entire website recursively (aby kind of links, not only HTML files)?

Comment: That question has been [asked](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100570/getting-files-all-at-once-from-a-web-page-using-curl) [before](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97834/how-can-i-download-all-mp3-files-from-a-web-site?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

**[Sitesucker](http://www.sitesucker.us/mac/mac.html)** isn't freeware, but it's exactly what you're looking for. I use it all the time. It costs $4.99 through the App Store.

> "SiteSucker is a Macintosh application that automatically downloads Web
>   sites from the Internet. It does this by asynchronously copying the
>   site's Web pages, images, backgrounds, movies, and other files to your
>   local hard drive, duplicating the site's directory structure. Just
>   enter a URL (Uniform Resource Locator), press return, and SiteSucker
>   can download an entire Web site."

Best of luck.